# How to write a procedure in Oracle that has the entries from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have used the following code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_details (
  start_time IN  DATE,
  End_Time   IN  DATE,
  o_results1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results3 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_results1 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   Table1
  WHERE  date_time BETEWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  OPEN o_results2 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   Table2
  WHERE  date_time BETEWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  OPEN o_results3 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   Table3
  WHERE  date_time BETEWEEN start_time AND End_Time;
END;
/
```

On doing the following:

```
VARIABLE o_result1 REFCURSOR; 
VARIABLE o_result2 REFCURSOR; 
VARIABLE o_result3 REFCURSOR; 
EXECUTE get_details( TO_DATE('15-Jul-15 04:00:10', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('15-Jul-15 20:14:16', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), :o_result1, :o_result2, :o_result3 );
```

I am not getting the values. I end up with ***no rows selected*** all the time when I do
`PRINT o_result1;` or any other variable print.

I need to print the values between the start time and the end time from the three tables that have date_time as a common field. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Congratulations for reinventing the **Y2K Bug**. An year is supposed to be 4 digits `YYYY`. What is `99`? Is it `1999` or `2099`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is wrong.

It has to be like,

```
TO_DATE('15-Jul-2015 04:00:10', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

`'15','YYYY'` will be interpreted as `0015`. Not 2015.

It has to be either `'15','RR'` or `'2015','YYYY'`

`RR` would be relative to current century.

ANd the final query would be,

```
EXECUTE get_details(
              TO_DATE('15-Jul-15 04:00:10', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 
              TO_DATE('15-Jul-15 20:14:16', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 
              :o_result1,
              :o_result2,
              :o_result3 );
```

Comment: Is there a way I can edit the information I get and display only the fields that are not null? 
say, I want only 2 fields. If both are null, then I don't want to display that row at all.

Comment: only way is to filter it out in the `where` clause. Example `select coalesce (col1,col2) as mycol where col1 is not null and col2 is not null` . `Coalesce`  would actually, return the first not null value passed to it.

Comment: Ok, how about this. Is there a way to print if say one of the tables return nothing. So say table2 has no results between the timeframe, is there a way to display that?

Comment: Yes, you have to actually check of data exists, before returning into cursor. `SELECT 'Y' into value_exists from dual where exists (<your select query>)`. Now , you know to open the cursor or not..